# What is a neat way to append into a dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is more of a design/data structure choice.

I find myself often having a dictionary of multiple keys with lists of their values, as such

```
        result_dict: Dict = {"model_name": [], "seed": [], "fold": [], "val_mse": []}
        result_dict["model_name"].append(model_name)
        result_dict["seed"].append(seed)
        result_dict["fold"].append(fold)
        result_dict["val_mse"].append(val_score)
        ......
```

This often gets cumbersome as I may even go up to storing 10 keys in a dictionary. What is an more optimal way to store without doing the way above?

---

My purpose of this dictionary has 2 reasons:

1. I can easily put it in a dataframe: `result_df = pd.DataFrame(data=result_dict)`
2. I may dump this dictionary into a `json` file for store keeping - after all, the results I get needs to be stored somewhere, for further purposes like plotting, saving, for future comparisons.

---

My code is as follows:

```
    result_dict: Dict = {"model_name": [], "seed": [], "identifier": [], "val_mse": []}

    model_name = model.__class__.__name__

    for fold in range(1, num_folds + 1):

        train_df = df_folds[df_folds["fold"] != fold].reset_index(drop=True)
        val_df = df_folds[df_folds["fold"] == fold].reset_index(drop=True)

        X_train, y_train = train_df[predictor_col].values, train_df[target_col].values
        X_val, y_val = val_df[predictor_col].values, val_df[target_col].values

        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_val_pred = model.predict(X_val)
        val_score = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true=y_val, y_pred=y_val_pred)

        result_dict["model_name"].append(model_name)
        result_dict["seed"].append(seed)
        result_dict["identifier"].append(f"fold {fold}")
        result_dict["val_mse"].append(val_score)

    avg_val_score = np.mean(result_dict["val_mse"], axis=None)
    standard_error = np.std(result_dict["val_mse"], axis=None) / np.sqrt(num_folds)
    result_dict["identifier"].append("average_score")
    result_dict["val_mse"].append(avg_val_score)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the data structure? What kind of operations, besides creating (with appending) are you using this dictionary for?

Comment: @DaniMesejo I will edit the question.

Comment: where do you get `model_name`, `seed `,etc from? (the data you append to the list)

Comment: You can have list of tuples (e.g. `data=[(v1, v2, v3), ...]` and then creating the dataframe with `pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["model_name", "seed", "fold"])`

Comment: How about `result_dict: Dict = {"model_name": ['model_name1'], "seed": ['seed1','seed3'], "fold": ['fold9'], "val_mse": ['val56']}` ?

Comment: @balderman I get those in a for loop.

Comment: What is the data structure you are looping on - share it in the post.

Comment: @balderman I shared the pseudocode that I am using, I soon realized it may be infeasible as I may keep appending stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is like the below (pay attention to `val_score` as an example)

```
 val_scores = []
 for fold in range(1, num_folds + 1):
    train_df = df_folds[df_folds["fold"] != fold].reset_index(drop=True)
    val_df = df_folds[df_folds["fold"] == fold].reset_index(drop=True)

    X_train, y_train = train_df[predictor_col].values, train_df[target_col].values
    X_val, y_val = val_df[predictor_col].values, val_df[target_col].values

    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_val_pred = model.predict(X_val)
    val_scores.append(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true=y_val, y_pred=y_val_pred))

 result_dict["val_mse"] = val_scores
```